# How to read commands from a text file

Tags: command-line, microsoft-windows

I would like to write some commands into one file and then I want the command line to read the file and do all commands inside the file. Step by step. For example:

```
C:\Users> project1.exe   < text1.txt   > data1.txt
C:\Users> project2.exe   < text2.txt   > data2.txt
C:\Users> project3.exe   < text3.txt   > data3.txt
```

Now, I have to write it step by step. I am using *Windows 7 Home Premium*. I am not a programmer.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not even remotely related to Elementary OS nor Linux at all

Answer (score 1):

If your question deals with Microsoft Windows OS you are in the wrong place as this forum deals with elementary OS (a Gnu-Linux) distribution.

In any case if you search "batch in windows 7" (something similar to scripts in gnu-linux) in the search engine you use in your browser you will get an idea of what you are asking for.

If you have more questions refered to Windows 7 you should try:
 https://www.sevenforums.com 
or look for other forums with the search engine you use.

Comment: Thank you.Your advice has helped me. I has been batch file.